# SSL Validation for DOD Websites in Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script

We've recently bounced up against a bug seemingly caused by a change made to the way Google is handling SSL trust in Google Apps Script on the Google Apps for Gov service. We have a few Apps Script systems - two in particular are a server monitoring system and a webservice-based calendar synchronization tool - which communicate with servers at our end over an SSL connection. This has worked fine for months, until ~9:15 PM on 20 Sept 2012, when almost all of these (and similar) connections began to fail due to an inability to trust the DOD-signed certificates which are mandatory for us on our end of things.

Stranger still is that this is somewhat inconsistent -- that is, I can successfully ask Google to connect to https://usuportal.usuhs.mil and it loads just fine. However, if I try any of:

https://www.us.army.mil

https://www.nps.edu

https://www.disa.mil

https://learning.usuhs.edu

... they all fail.  I suspect that this is to do with the root cert which some servers tie themselves back to, suffice that all tying back to the "DOD Root CA-2" certificate as a terminator are failing - a real problem for us.

For our server monitoring we've been able to temporarily work around this by disabling SSL verification in Apps Script, but that option isn't available for accessing webservices [EDIT: we are using SoapService to handle WS requests and returns], leaving us unable to continue to use those tools for as long as this problem is in place. Given the precision with which we can identify when the relevant change happened, though, I should hope Google can at least (relatively) quickly pinpoint what happened.

If it's helpful, below is a quick Google Apps Script function which will log out success / failure based on whether it's able to trust the SSL certificate at the endpoint.

```
function checkSSL()
{
// The server to go look at to see if we can trust it.
// Again, usuportal.usuhs.mil has been observed to work; all others tested have failed
//
var serverToTest = "https://www.disa.mil";

// options defines the options which will be used by the UrlFetchApp to define its behavior.
// In this case, we may be interested in disabling SSL validation.
//

var options =
{
    "validateHttpsCertificates" : false
};

// First, try without disabling validation
//
try {
    response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(serverToTest);
    Logger.log("I was able to reach " + serverToTest +" without disabling certificate validation.");
}
catch (e)
{
    // Logger.log(e.toString());
    Logger.log("I was not able to reach " + serverToTest +" without disabling certificate validation.");
}

// Now let's try it with validation disabled
//
try {
    response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(serverToTest, options);
    Logger.log("I was able to reach " + serverToTest +" with certificate validation disabled.");
}
catch (e)
{
    // Logger.log(e.toString());
    Logger.log("I was not able to reach " + serverToTest +" with certificate validation disabled. Maybe it's really just down?");
}
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "webservices"? Don't you access them using UrlFetch as well?

Comment: Sorry, I probably should have been more clear -- it's the SoapService for which I do not appear to be able to override SSL validation (nor, IMO, should I have to).  Thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: Oh, ok. I think only a googler can answer this question. I tried to get their attention by sharing this with the ones I know on g+. But if no one comes, you should open an issue on our [tracker](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/list). As this is really well described and seems like a real bug to me.

Answer (score 1):

Please log this in the [Issue Tracker](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/list). I've been able to dive into this internally and this is in fact and issue we believe. Once you log it in the Issue Tracker you'll be able to follow along the progress of this issue.

We'll likely solve this by adding in a similar "validateHttpsCertificates" flag for SoapSerivce like with UrlFetchApp

Comment: By the way, this issue should now be fixed. Please confirm.

Comment: Arun - this has now been worked around for many users, but unfortunately we won't be able to work with that implementation for the security implications of unvalidated SSL connections.  Great turnaround on the fix for the general public, and we hope you're given the leeway to take a more general solution in the future.  Thank you!